# Use of GraphLayout on a set of Feynman Graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have written a piece of code that produces all connected Feynman Graphs for a given polynomial theory up to certain no of internal vertices. Now, I want to modify the default layout of the graphs generated. Here is a snapshot of some of the graphs I have:

[image: Feynman Graphs]

Now, what I desire to have is that:

1. **Central internal vertices** should be symmetrically in a **straight line**
2. **Branches** from that main line would be **radially outward**.
3. **Loops must be circular**(not polygonal)
4. Loops must be **placed upright** and not upside down.

These requirements might not be precise enough to completely characterize a layout. I would be more than happy to see the closest one can get.

Here is a picture of some of the modified versions of the default graph layouts that follow the rules I listed above:

[image: Desired modifications in graph layout]

**So, how could one use GraphLayout options effectively to achieve this?**

Here is the list of graphs that can be used as a sample:

```
 list = {Graph[List[1], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 1], UndirectedEdge[1, 1]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 2], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, 2], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, 2]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 2], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 1], UndirectedEdge[1, 2], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[2, 2]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 2, 3], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, 3], UndirectedEdge[1, 3], UndirectedEdge[2, 2],
      UndirectedEdge[2, 3]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 2, 3], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, 2], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, 3], UndirectedEdge[1, 3], UndirectedEdge[2, 3],
      UndirectedEdge[2, 3]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 3, 2], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 1], UndirectedEdge[1, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, 3], UndirectedEdge[2, 2], UndirectedEdge[2, 3],
      UndirectedEdge[2, 3]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 2, 3], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 1], UndirectedEdge[1, 2], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, 3], UndirectedEdge[2, 2], UndirectedEdge[2, 3],
      UndirectedEdge[3, 3]]], 
   Graph[List[1, s[0], s[1]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 1], UndirectedEdge[1, s[0]], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, s[1]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 2, s[2], s[3]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, 2], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, s[2]], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, s[3]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 3, 2, s[6], s[7]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 3], UndirectedEdge[1, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, 2], UndirectedEdge[2, 3], UndirectedEdge[2, 3],
      UndirectedEdge[1, s[6]], UndirectedEdge[1, s[7]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 2, 3, s[8], s[9]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, 3], UndirectedEdge[2, 3], UndirectedEdge[2, 3],
      UndirectedEdge[1, s[8]], UndirectedEdge[1, s[9]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 2, 3, s[14], s[15]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, 2], UndirectedEdge[2, 3], UndirectedEdge[3, 3],
      UndirectedEdge[1, s[14]], UndirectedEdge[1, s[15]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, s[24], s[25], s[26], s[27]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, s[24]], UndirectedEdge[1, s[25]], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, s[26]], UndirectedEdge[1, s[27]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 2, s[44], s[45]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, 2], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, s[44]], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, s[45]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 2, s[46], s[47]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 1], UndirectedEdge[1, 2], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, s[46]], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, s[47]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 3, 2, s[48], s[49]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 3], UndirectedEdge[1, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, 3], UndirectedEdge[2, 2], UndirectedEdge[2, 3],
      UndirectedEdge[1, s[48]], UndirectedEdge[2, s[49]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 2, 3, s[50], s[51]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, 3], UndirectedEdge[2, 3], UndirectedEdge[2, 3],
      UndirectedEdge[1, s[50]], UndirectedEdge[2, s[51]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 2, 3, s[54], s[55]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, 3], UndirectedEdge[2, 2], UndirectedEdge[3, 3],
      UndirectedEdge[1, s[54]], UndirectedEdge[2, s[55]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 2, 3, s[56], s[57]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, 2], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, 3], UndirectedEdge[2, 3], UndirectedEdge[3, 3],
      UndirectedEdge[1, s[56]], UndirectedEdge[2, s[57]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 3, 2, s[58], s[59]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 1], UndirectedEdge[1, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, 2], UndirectedEdge[2, 3], UndirectedEdge[3, 3],
      UndirectedEdge[1, s[58]], UndirectedEdge[2, s[59]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 2, s[66], s[67], s[68], s[69]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[2, 2], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, s[66]], UndirectedEdge[1, s[67]], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, s[68]], UndirectedEdge[2, s[69]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 3, 2, s[70], s[71], s[72], s[73]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 3], UndirectedEdge[2, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, 3], UndirectedEdge[2, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, s[70]], UndirectedEdge[1, s[71]], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, s[72]], UndirectedEdge[2, s[73]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 3, 2, s[74], s[75], s[76], s[77]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 3], UndirectedEdge[2, 2], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, 3], UndirectedEdge[3, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, s[74]], UndirectedEdge[1, s[75]], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, s[76]], UndirectedEdge[2, s[77]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 2, 3, s[78], s[79], s[80], s[81]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[2, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, 3], UndirectedEdge[3, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, s[78]], UndirectedEdge[1, s[79]], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, s[80]], UndirectedEdge[2, s[81]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 2, s[108], s[109], s[110], s[111]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, 2], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, s[108]], UndirectedEdge[1, s[109]], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, s[110]], UndirectedEdge[2, s[111]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 3, 2, s[116], s[117], s[118], s[119]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 3], UndirectedEdge[1, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, 3], UndirectedEdge[2, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, s[116]], UndirectedEdge[1, s[117]], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, s[118]], UndirectedEdge[2, s[119]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 2, 3, s[124], s[125], s[126], s[127]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, 3], UndirectedEdge[3, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, s[124]], UndirectedEdge[1, s[125]], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, s[126]], UndirectedEdge[2, s[127]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 2, s[178], s[179], s[180], s[181], s[182], s[183]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, s[178]], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, s[179]], UndirectedEdge[1, s[180]], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, s[181]], UndirectedEdge[2, s[182]], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, s[183]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 3, 2, s[184], s[185], s[186], s[187], s[188], 
     s[189]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 3], UndirectedEdge[2, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[3, 3], UndirectedEdge[1, s[184]], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, s[185]], UndirectedEdge[1, s[186]], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, s[187]], UndirectedEdge[2, s[188]], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, s[189]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 3, 2, s[298], s[299], s[300], s[301]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 3], UndirectedEdge[1, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, 2], UndirectedEdge[2, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, s[298]], UndirectedEdge[1, s[299]], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, s[300]], UndirectedEdge[3, s[301]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 2, 3, s[302], s[303], s[304], s[305]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, 3], UndirectedEdge[2, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, s[302]], UndirectedEdge[1, s[303]], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, s[304]], UndirectedEdge[3, s[305]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 2, 3, s[310], s[311], s[312], s[313]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, 2], UndirectedEdge[3, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, s[310]], UndirectedEdge[1, s[311]], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, s[312]], UndirectedEdge[3, s[313]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 3, 2, s[358], s[359], s[360], s[361], s[362], 
     s[363]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 3], UndirectedEdge[2, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, 3], UndirectedEdge[1, s[358]], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, s[359]], UndirectedEdge[1, s[360]], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, s[361]], UndirectedEdge[2, s[362]], 
     UndirectedEdge[3, s[363]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 2, 3, s[370], s[371], s[372], s[373], s[374], 
     s[375]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[2, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[3, 3], UndirectedEdge[1, s[370]], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, s[371]], UndirectedEdge[1, s[372]], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, s[373]], UndirectedEdge[2, s[374]], 
     UndirectedEdge[3, s[375]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 2, 3, s[564], s[565], s[566], s[567], s[568], 
     s[569]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, 3], UndirectedEdge[1, s[564]], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, s[565]], UndirectedEdge[2, s[566]], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, s[567]], UndirectedEdge[3, s[568]], 
     UndirectedEdge[3, s[569]]]], 
   Graph[List[1, 3, 2, s[622], s[623], s[624], s[625], s[626], s[627],
      s[628], s[629]], 
    List[UndirectedEdge[1, 3], UndirectedEdge[2, 3], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, s[622]], UndirectedEdge[1, s[623]], 
     UndirectedEdge[1, s[624]], UndirectedEdge[2, s[625]], 
     UndirectedEdge[2, s[626]], UndirectedEdge[2, s[627]], 
     UndirectedEdge[3, s[628]], UndirectedEdge[3, s[629]]]], 
   Graph[List[s[974], s[975]], List[UndirectedEdge[s[974], s[975]]]]};
```

Comment: Check out FeynEdit from http://www.feynarts.de/

Comment: @RolfMertig I know about the program. I wanted to achieve this by myself as it will help me easily make modifications for cases that are not so common.

Comment: I don't think you can use `GraphLayout`. You would need to compute and set your own `VertexCoordinates`, and to deal with loops, also your own `EdgeShapeFunction`.  Could you give a more precise description of the layout?  E.g., in your examples, column 2, row 3, there's a tree. You put 4 vertices on a straight horizontal line. Why these 4 vertices specifically, why not others?  Also, why 4?  We could put 5 on a straight line (and have more braches emanating from that line).